# Codekit with Ampps browser refreshing not working

Tags: codekit, ampps

Was hoping if someone could help me figure this out. When I click on "preview" in codekit I get

"Unable to preview

CodeKit's internal server is not running. Various network issues can cause this, including certain VPNs. Disable any VPNs and/or reboot your Mac and try again"

If I turn off the servers in Ampps, codekit attempts to but I just get an error since Ampps isn't running to serve the page.

Any ideas on what to do? I've been goig through all the settings in Ampps trying to find something, but I'm coming up empty.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. It was a firewall causing the issue. TCP block to be specific. I disabled it and all was good.